# Derivative for summation of two-function product

Tags: derivatives

Suppose that I have $f(x) = \text{ln}\Big(1 + \sum_{i=1}^{I}p_i(x)q_i(x)\Big)$. I want to find $f'(x)$. Based on my understanding, I would obtain:

$f'(x) = \frac{1}{1 + \sum_{i=1}^{I}p_i(x)q_i(x)}\frac{d}{dx}\Big(1 + \sum_{i=1}^{I}p_i(x)q_i(x)\Big)$

$f'(x) = \frac{1}{1 + \sum_{i=1}^{I}p_i(x)q_i(x)}\frac{d}{dx}\Big( \sum_{i=1}^{I}p_i(x)q_i(x)\Big)$

However, I do not know how to solve $\frac{d}{dx}\Big( \sum_{i=1}^{I}p_i(x)q_i(x)\Big)$. How to solve it?

Comment: It's $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^I\left[p_i'(x)q_i(x)+p_i(x)q_i'(x)\right].$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{d}{dx}\Big( \sum_{i=1}^{I}p_i(x)q_i(x)\Big)$$
$$=\frac{d}{dx}\Big( p_1(x)q_1(x)+p_2(x)q_2(x)+\cdots +p_I(x)q_I(x)\Big)$$
$$=p_1'(x)q_1(x)+p_1(x)q_1'(x)+p_2'(x)q_2(x)+p_2(x)q_2'(x)+\cdots+p_I'(x)q_I(x)+p_I(x)q_I'(x)$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^{I}\Big(p_i'(x)q_i(x)+p_i(x)q_i'(x)\Big)$$